# Will this converge to origine?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

- Suppose you have a diffusion of 100 points with the following iteration:

$$(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \sim \mathcal{N}\left((x_n,y_n),  \frac{x_n^2 + y_n^2}{2} I_{2 \times2}\right)$$

- This will make a high variance for the points far from the origin and a low variance for the points close to the origin. ( The above equation is just a try to imitate this idea. We can use different equations.)
- I think most of the points will come close to the origin after some time.

#### Question

- Do you also think that?
- Is there any theorem through which we can prove the above?
- Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{N}\left((x_n,y_n),  \frac{x_n^2 + y_n^2}{2}\right)$? Shouldn't there be a $2 \times 2$ variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yeah, I corrected it.

Comment: I did a few simulations. Results suggest that this process diverges even if the initial point is very close to the origin.

Comment: Isn't$E(r_{n+1}^2)=\frac32r_n^2$?

Comment: @Ricky Can you share those with us? Code or plots.

Comment: @Empy2, it's $2r_n^2$, if I'm not mistaken. Also one has to define the notation before using it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence of points will diverge to infinity.

We can write the updates of the Markov chain $\left\{\left(x_n, y_n\right)\right\}_n$ as
$$ \left(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}\right) = \left(x_n, y_n\right) + \sqrt{\frac{x^2_n + y_n^2}{2}} Z_{n+1},$$
where $\left\{Z_n\right\}_n$ is an independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) sequence of standard two-dimensional Gaussian random variables. Define by $r_n^2 = x_n^2 + y_n^2$ the squared distance from the origin. The sequence $\left\{r_n^2\right\}_n$ satisfies the following recurrence
$$r_{n+1}^2 = \left(1+ \sqrt{2}\left\langle \frac{\left(x_n, y_n\right)}{\sqrt{x^2_n + y_n^2}}, Z_{n+1}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{n+1}\right|^2\right)r_n^2. $$
This sequence is equal in law to the sequence $\left\{\tilde{r}_n\right\}$ given by $\tilde{r}_0 = r_0$ and
$$\tilde{r}_n = \left(1+ \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1,0\right), Z_{n+1}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{n+1}\right|^2\right)
\tilde{r}_n^2, $$
since a standard Gaussian is invariant by rotation. Furthermore $\left\{\tilde{r}_n\right\}$ is a Markov chain.
We can then consider the logarithm of this chain, $q_n = \log\left(\tilde{r}_n^2\right)$, which satisfies
$$q_{n+1} = q_n + \log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{n+1}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{n+1}\right|^2\right).$$
$q_n - q_0$ is the sum of i.i.d random variables
$$ q_n - q_0 = \sum_{k = 1}^n \log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{k}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{k}\right|^2\right).$$
We can check that $ \log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{1}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{1}\right|^2\right)$ is square-integrable and numerically estimate its mean, $\mu$, and variance, $\sigma^2$,
$$ \mu = \mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{k}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{k}\right|^2\right)\right] \approx 0.219, $$
$$ \sigma^2 = \mathrm{Var}\left(\log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{k}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{k}\right|^2\right)\right) \approx 1.376.$$
So by the strong law of large numbers,
$$\frac{q_n - q_0}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \log\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\left\langle \left(1, 0\right), Z_{k}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left|Z_{k}\right|^2\right) \to \mu >0 \quad \text{almost surely,}$$
which in turn implies that $q_n \to \infty$ almost surely. Consequently, $r_n$ also converges to $\infty$ almost surely and the chain $\left\{\left(x_n, y_n\right)\right\}_n$ diverges.